# how to get touch event on specified CGRectMake

Tags: iphone

I want to get touch event on UIImageView with specified location only.

```
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint=[touch locationInView:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
```

CGRectMake(0,0,100,100) In the specific location i need touche event, is it possible.
What to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In touchesBegan and touchesMoved:

```
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint=[touch locationInView:self];

CGRect testRect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);

if(CGRectContainsPoint(testRect, currentPoint)) {
     //For if you are touching the 100 x 100 rectangle...
}
```

Comment: If it's working fine, you should give credit to the person that answered by accepting their answer. See the stackoverflow FAQ for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @GreglnYeg. I do not have any idea about crediting to the person.  i just click now check mark.  Is that i credited thyrgle.